# Remove fancyhdr footer when float page too large

Tags: floats, header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm working on a book with `fancyhdr` with some overfull float pages, and want to remove the footer on only those pages, but keep the header.

Can I either automatically remove footer if the caption writes over it or include something in the caption which does that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textsl{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textsl{\leftmark}}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{First}
text

\begin{figure}[p]
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{small figure page, print page number}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
\rule{10cm}{20.8cm}
\caption{large figure page, don't print page number}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

PS: Can I deactivate the "float too large" warning if it fits on the page once the footer is removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't offer a solution for `fancyhdr`, but the recently released [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) package features (among other things) the commands `\nextfloathead` and `\nextfloatfoot` which force a header/footer for the float immediately following these commands.

Note that `titleps` uses a pagestyle definition syntax rather different from those of `fancyhdr` and the `scrpage2` package -- see section 2 of the `titleps` manual for details, particularly about the `\sethead` and `\setfoot` commands.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[psfloats]{titleps}

\renewpagestyle{headings}{%
  \headrule
  \sethead[\textsl{\thechapter~\chaptertitle}][][]
      {}{}{\textsl{\thesection~\sectiontitle}}%
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}%
}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
  \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}%
}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{First}

text

\begin{figure}[p]
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{small figure page, print page number}
\end{figure}

\nextfloatfoot{}{}{}{}

\begin{figure}[p]
\rule{10cm}{20.8cm}
\caption{large figure page, don't print page number}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```